# Making video with overlay view in AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession, google-vision

I'm trying to capture video with an overlay view using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer, but the video is saving without the overlay view. Basically my app is setting an object instead of a face, which works fine and I am able to take images as well (see the link below). Capturing the video is the only issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5T15.jpg

CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescriptionRef = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer);

```
        const AudioStreamBasicDescription *audioStreamBasicDescription = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(fdesc);

        _sampleRate = audioStreamBasicDescription -> mSampleRate;
        _audioChannel = audioStreamBasicDescription -> mChannelsPerFrame;

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm:ss";
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
        NSString *currentDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
        NSString *videoName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"video_%@.mp4", currentDateString];
        _videoPath = [self.cacheDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoName];
        _resolutionWidth  = 360;
        _resolutionHeight = 640;
        _recordingWriter = [VideoRecordingWriter recordingWriterWithVideoPath:_videoPath
                                                              resolutionWidth:_resolutionWidth resolutionHeight:_resolutionHeight
                                                                 audioChannel:_audioChannel sampleRate:_sampleRate];

        CMTime presentationTimeStamp = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer);
        if (_startRecordingCMTime.value == 0) {
            _startRecordingCMTime = presentationTimeStamp;
        }

        CMTime subtract = CMTimeSubtract(presentationTimeStamp, _startRecordingCMTime);
        _currentRecordingTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(subtract);
        if (_currentRecordingTime > _maxRecordingTime) {
            if (_currentRecordingTime - _maxRecordingTime >= 0.1) {
                return;
            }
        }
        [_recordingWriter writeWithSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer isVideo:YES];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self updateRecordingProgress:_currentRecordingTime / _maxRecordingTime];
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide code on what you have tried, that's the only way anyone can help you.

Comment: updated my video saving code

Answer (score 0):

```
func startCapturing(view: SKView, background: CALayer, done: @escaping((_:CALayer)->())) {
    let device = getCamera()!

    do {
        captureSession.beginConfiguration()

        // Set up INPUTS
        try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device))

        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

        if let previewLayer = previewLayer {
            // add background
            previewLayer.addSublayer(background)

            // init preview
            previewLayer.name = "camera"
            previewLayer.frame.size = view.bounds.size
            if IS_DEBUG {
                print("VideoService: size of previewLayer")
                print(previewLayer.frame.size)
            }
            previewLayer.position = CGPoint(
                x: view.frame.width/2, y: view.frame.height/2)
            view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            done(previewLayer)
        }
        captureSession.commitConfiguration()
        captureSession.startRunning()

        print("\n\nVideoService: camera configured")
    } catch {
        print("Error: start capturing failed")
    }
}

func getCaptureSessionBack() -> AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession {
    session = session ?? AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(
        deviceTypes: [deviceTypeBackCamera],
        mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
        position: position)
    return session!
}

func getCamera() -> AVCaptureDevice? {
    device = device ?? getCaptureSessionBack().devices.first
    return device
}
```

Comment: i need to use spirit kit for this? sry i dont have any idea about it

Comment: its like a 3D object, so when user walk around it will visible from all angles in video like snapchat.